# How to reference an algorithm within an algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I have two algorithms, algorithm 2 depends on algorithm 1. I would like to reference algorithm 1 at the beginning of algorithm 2, writing something of the form

Get H from algorithm 1

And then continue with the rest of algorithm 2. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Welcome! Although you got an answer this time, please be sure to include code for a minimal example next time. That makes it much easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

Self explanatory. Just use `\ref{label}` in the second algorithm, see below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{caption Allo}\label{algo:allo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Allo}{$a,b$}       \Comment{comments}
    \State System Initialization
    \State Read the value 
    \If{$condition = True$}
        \State Do action
    \EndIf
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{caption Patato}\label{algo:patato}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Patato}{$a,b$}   
    \State Get H from Algorithm \ref{algo:allo}
    \If{$condition = True$}
        \State Do action
    \EndIf
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```